# how to build and configure kernel and file system for UML in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: kernel

I saw many links for for UML but all just pointed to install UML for fedora is there a way i could config UML in ubuntu using Ubuntu file system mine is a 64 bit computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian and Ubuntu provide a [rootstrap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/rootstrap) command that can build a
Ubuntu (or Debian) filesystem for you to use with [User-Mode Linux](http://user-mode-linux.sf.net)

1. On your computer, install the packages *user-mode-linux*, *slirp* and *rootstrap*.
2. Note that rootstrap earlier than 0.3.24-6 does not run with Python >= 2.6
   You need to apply the patch provided at:
   http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=585352
   if you are running an old version of rootstrap.
   (The version shipped with Ubuntu 11.10 "oneiric" is OK.)
3. Create a `rootstrap.conf` configuration file (you can use the one
   provided in `/etc/rootstrap/rootstrap.conf` as a reference):

   ```
   [global]
   # Initial size of the filesystem image (in MBs). It will be created
   # sparsely, so additional space is not allocated until it is used.
   initialsize=1024
   # the filesystem to create
   fstype=ext2
   # rootstrap modules to run to create the initial image
   modules=network mkfs mount debian uml umount
   # rootstraps' defaults are too low for installing recent Ubuntu/Debian
   umlargs= mem=512M

   [network]
   # name of the network interface inside the UML
   interface=eth0
   transport=slirp
   # note: the following settings were copied verbatim from
   # /etc/rootstrap/rootstrap.conf; they're slirp's defaults, tho
   host=
   uml=10.0.2.15
   nameserver=10.0.2.3
   gateway=10.0.2.2
   netmask=255.255.0.0
   slirp=slirp-fullbolt

   [debian]
   dist=oneiric
   mirror=http://archive.ubuntu.com/
   ```
4. Now run the command *rootstrap* in the same directory where you
   created the configuration file:

   ```
   rootstrap my-disk-image.img
   ```

You can read more about the use of *rootstrap* in its [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/rootstrap).

Answer (score 1):

The ubuntu wiki page is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UserModeLinux).  All the referenced packages still exist.